# Dynamic array stack struct C

Tags: c, struct, typedef

I have a couple of questions. I have a bit of a hard time understanding this code. What exactly is it doing?

For example:

What does typedef struct dynArrStruct do and why does it have dynArr at the end of it? I know the definition of typedef as "allows to created alias for a known data type" but that is jargon to me. Can someone try to put it in layman terms? Thank you!

Why are there 2 struct variables (a1/a2)?

Link to full code if needed:

http://www.cs.uic.edu/pub/CS211/CS211LectureNotesS13/dynArr.c

```
typedef struct dynArrStruct
{
    double *location;
    int length;
    int currSize;
} dynArr;

int main (int argc, char**argv)
{
    struct dynArrStruct a1;
    dynArr a2;
    int i;

    //rest of code
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What does `typedef struct dynArrStruct` do and why does it have `dynArr` at the end of it?

The `typedef` creates an alias to a type to save you some typing, or to improve readability. In this particular case, it creates an alias called `dynArr` for the `struct dynArrStruct`.

Without a `typedef`, i.e. with only this

```
struct dynArrStruct
{
    double *location;
    int length;
    int currSize;
};
```

you would be forced to write `struct dynArrStruct` every time you need to declare a variable of that `struct`'s type. With a `typedef` in place, you can write simply `dynArr`, and the compiler will interpret it as the `struct dynArrStruct` for you.

Comment: So would it be ideal to always typedef every struct?

Comment: it is also possible to fully omit the word `dynArrStruct` in the code, making the expression `struct dynArrStruct` of course invalid and should replaced with `dynArr` in main()

Comment: @juice Yes, that is correct. In fact, many C programming shops require programmers to `typedef` every `struct` they may define, and provide coding standards explaining how the naming of the two should be related. Moreover, C++ does this for you by default - it is sufficient to declare a `struct` without a `typedef`, and the name of the `struct` would become usable without the `struct` keyword.

Comment: Thanks everyone I really appreciate you all helping me understand this.

Answer (score 2):

```
typedef struct dynArrStruct
{
    double *location;
    int length;
    int currSize;
} dynArr;
```

Is a short form of two different pieces of code.

```
// define a struct by name dynArrStruct
struct dynArrStruct
{
    double *location;
    int length;
    int currSize;
}; 

//Example of use
struct dynArrStruct d1;
```

and

```
// define an alias to "struct dynArrStruct" called dynArr
typedef struct dynArrStruct dynArr; 


//Example of use
dynArr d2; //whoa so short!
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to dasblinkenlight's answer,

```
Why are there 2 struct variables (a1/a2)?
```

The code presented appears to be an example of poorly modularised code (a1) and well modularised code (a2). The modifications made to `a1` are very similar to the modifications made to `a2`. However, the modifications made to `a2` are abstracted out into functions (lines 53-55 correspond to the lines found in `init`, 57-58 correspond to the lines found in `push` and `push`), so that that functionality can be easily reused. An example of this reuse is lines 69-72.